# Kial kompreni "la" horloĝon?

Tags: word-usage

Duolingo diras: "La infano volas kompreni la horloĝon".

(Vidu ĉe la Duolinga forumo: [eo→en](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/8879148), [en→eo](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/15769040).)

Mi komprenas la frazon tiel kiel l'infano volas lerni horloĝ-sistemon unuafoje en sia vivo. Do, kial oni devas diri ke l'infano volas kompreni "la" horloĝon? **Kial oni diras tion uzante "la"?** Laŭ mi, la frazo kun "la", signifas ke l'infano volas kompreni kiel funkcias la horloĝo en la ĉambro de siaj gepatroj, ekzemple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verŝajne tio estas ekzemplo de tio kion [PMEG nomas](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/difiniloj/la/specoj.html#i-1sn) “Speco kvazaŭ konata individuo”:

> Iafoje oni rigardas specon kiel unu imagan konatan individuon, kaj uzas *la*. Tio estas sufiĉe ofta en formala aŭ filozofieca stilo. En tiaj okazoj temas klare pri la tuta speco:
>
> ***La gitaro** estas tre populara instrumento.* Oni prezentas instrumentospecon kvazaŭ temus pri unu certa konata instrumento. Ankaŭ eblus: ***Gitaro** estas...*

Mi pensas ke se oni dirus “la infano volas kompreni horloĝon”, ankaŭ tio estus konfuza, ĉar mi pensus ke ĝi estus kiel “estas iu horloĝo ie, kiun vi ne konas, kaj la infano volas kompreni ĝin”. Eble alternativo povus esti “la infanoj volas kompreni horloĝojn”. Tiel estas pli probable ke oni komprenus ke temas pri horloĝoj ĝenerale.

Mi supozas ke ĉiuj tri manieroj estas ambiguaj, sed en la kunteksto tio verŝajne ne estas problemo.

Comment: Dankon Sinjoro @neil-roberts pro via respondo. Nun mi komprenas ties kialon.

Answer (score 1):

Temas pri horloĝoj ĝenerale. Se Esperanto havus nedifinitan artikolon, mi povus klarigi ke ne temas pri "iu horloĝo"